# Header ache - gap appears

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When starting the app I get the UI as I want it.  When returning to the same page I get the gap at the top.  How can I fix this?

All navigation uses the Application.Current.MainPage = new *SomePage*(); shape.

The XAML is trivial:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="ShipShapeMobile.LandingPage"
         BackgroundImage="Gradient640x1136.png"
         >
<ContentPage.Content >
    <Grid 
        x:Name="grid"
    >
        <StackLayout 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            >
            <Image
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="ShipShapeShipA448x591.png" 
                VerticalOptions="Center"
                Margin="50,15,50,15"
            />
            <Image
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Source="TextOnlySS.png" 
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            />

            <Image Source="hr7.png"  Margin="20,10,20,10" />

            <Button 
                x:Name="btnSignIn" 
                BackgroundColor="DodgerBlue" 
                BorderColor="White" 
                BorderWidth="1"
                Clicked="BtnSignIn_OnClicked"
                CornerRadius="15"
                Image="Icon29.png"
                Margin="50,10,50,10"
                Text="SIGN UP" 
                TextColor="White" 
            />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

[image: Good UI]
[image: Bad UI Grr]

Comment: try using this in your xaml `NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"` as a top tag  just below `BackgroundImage`

Comment: If you make this an answer I will mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in your `LandingPage` `NavigationBar` being displayed. Hide it in your xaml class itself.

```
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
```

Use this in your top tag of `ContentPage`.